# Java properties elements

Tags: java, xml, ssh, properties

I'm currently working on an application that will be used to power on/off a device (server) over SSH. Now I use a property file with the following settings:

```
command.power_on.name = Power on
command.power_on.host = host.com
command.power_on.user = user
command.power_on.password = password
command.power_on.port = 22
command.power_on.timeout = 10000
command.power_on.command = power on command

command.power_off.name = Power off
command.power_off.host = host.com
command.power_off.user = user
command.power_off.password = password
command.power_off.port = 22
command.power_off.timeout = 10000
command.power_off.command = power off command
```

I want to loop through all the commands and put them into List, Array, Object, Custom Object or whatever is possible.

*PSEUDO Code:*

```
String[] commands = propertiesConfiguration.getKeys("command");

for (String command : commands) {
    CommandModel[] commandModel = command; 

    /* Will return two command models with the power_on and power_off attributes.
    (name, host, user, password, port, timeout and command) */
}
```

And as result I want to get something like this (like in XML):

```
Command[] command; // Array with all the commands.

System.out.println(command[0].toString()); // Will print the "power_on" attributes.
System.out.println(command[1].toString()); // Will print the "power_off" attributes.

CommandModel commandModel = new CommandModel(); // The command model with queries (select, select all and update).

Command powerOn = commandModel.getCommand("power_on"); // Will return the command "power_on" with their attributes (name, host, user, password, port, timeout, command).
Command powerOff = commandModel.getCommand("power_off"); // Will return the command "power_off" with their attributes (name, host, user, password, port, timeout, command).
Command[] command = commandModel.getAll(); // Will return an array of all the commands.
```

I know this is possible with XML based structures, but is this also possible with a property based file? I have only 2 commands, I thought a property file will be enough for this. Or should I use a XML file?

All feedback, suggestions etc are welcome. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code sample will add the requested output objects in a map, having as key the name of the two wanted commands (poweroff and poweron). The fields are set using reflection.
Taking into consideration that the properties file is in the same folder where the application is run the following code sample will read all properties defined in the properties file.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("command.properties");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    // the output map that will contain the results
    // the poweroff related content for key "poweroff" 
    // the poweron related content for key "poweron"
    Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<>();

    properties.load(is);

    // parse the properties file
    for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> e :properties.entrySet()) {
        // extract the name of the object (poweroff or poweron)
        String name = name((String)e.getKey());
        // extract the name of the property to be set (timeout, host etc.)
        String property = property((String)e.getKey());

        // get the object where to set the outcome
        Command command = commands.get(name);

        // create the object if it wasn't already created
        // and add it to the map
        if (command == null) {
            command = new Command();

            commands.put(name, command);
        }

        // set the value of the given property on the corresponding object
        setValue(Command.class, command, property, e.getValue());
    }

    System.out.println(commands);
}

static String name(String input) {
    return input.split("\\.")[1];
}

static  String property(String input) {
    return input.split("\\.")[2];
}

static void setValue(Class<?> clazz, Object object, String propertyName, Object value) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(propertyName);

    field.setAccessible(true);

    field.set(object, value);
}

static class Command {
    String name;
    String host;
    String user;
    String password;
    String port;
    String timeout;
    String command;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + host + " " + user + " " + password + " " + port + " " + timeout + " " + command;
    }
}
```

Output: `{power_off=Power off host.com user password 22 10000 power off command, power_on=Power on host.com user password 22 10000 power on command}`

Comment: Thank your for your reply! I know how to read a properties file. But my problem is that I want to put the "power on and the power off" with their attributes into a new object. That's my question.

Comment: @nberlijn - I am working on updating the sample as we speak ;). How do you intend to use the output - the two command objects created?

Comment: I added a code example for the preferred result to the question :-) I Guess that I was not clear enough about what I want (only the topic title with "elements").

Comment: @nberlijn - please have a look at the example now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :-) This is the way were I was looking for. Do you maybe know if there are libraries around that support things like this? Or do I have to move on to XML libraries if I want the flexibility of "elements"?

Comment: @nberlijn - check the [apache commons project](https://commons.apache.org/). Might provide a way. But to be honest I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks! I tried apache commons project already before without succes. I guess the custom parser you made will be the way to go, I'm study the code now :-) Thank you again!

Comment: @nberlijn - I hope it helps you. Just write how I can improve the content and you can mark as response and/or up-vote it. So it helps others as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop all of your properties using the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `ResourceBundle` class [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).

The `getKeys()` method will return a Enumeration of `String`.
You can also get the values by using `getString(key)` method. It accepts a key as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class called

```
public class MyProperties{

private String key;
private String value;
//get/set() methods of key/value OR Create Constructor with Varaibles
}
```

Now Write this logic

```
 private List<MyProperties> createPropertyList(){
    Properties proObj = new Properties();
    proObj.load(new FileInputStream("PathOfPropertiesFile"));
    List<MyProperties> propertyList = new ArrayList<MyProperties>();
    for(String propertyKey: proObj.stringPropertyNames()) {
      MyProperties myProperties = new MyProperties();
      myProperties.setKey(propertyKey);
      myProperties.setValue(properties.getProperty(propertyKey));
      propertyList.add(myProperties);
    }
  return propertyList;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand this! This will add all the properties from the properties file as key-value pairs in a new MyProperties object. But I want to get a List with commands: (power on and power off) with their attributes (name, etc...), I don't know yet how to apply that.

Comment: You want this whole  `command.power_on.name = Power on` as a object?

Comment: JoshiI Yes! I added a code example for the preferred result to the question :-)

Comment: Please check the code which i have written You have List of record now you can get only values from this.

Comment: I tried to use your code! But it gives me only Keys and Values pairs. I want to get 2 objects (power on and power off) with their attributes (name, host, user, password, port, timeout, command).